Cómo puedo hacer que funcione una api rest en grails 1.3.7?
estoy en una empresa que trabaja con Grails 1.3.7 (sé que es una versión antigüa) y necesita crear una api para sus productos. En mi caso cee un pequeño caso de estudio para hacer las pruebas ahí, pero no logro que me funcione la API que estoy implementando. Intenté utilizar Swagger, pero no pude. Actualmente, lo que sucede es que ni el navegador, ni Postman encuentran la ruta.
A continuación, dejo una imagen con la jerarquía del proyecto y el código de los archivos correspondientes para que funcione la api. Espero que puedan ayudarme y gracias de antemano.
Esta es la jerarquía de mi caso de estudio

ProfesorApiController.groovy
(En teoría estos 2 métodos son los que debería consumir la API.)
package api

import curso.Profesor
import grails.converters.JSON

class ProfesorApiController {

    static allowedMethods = [mostrarProfesores: "GET", obtenerProfesorById: "GET"]

    def mostrarProfesores = {
        def profesores = Profesor.list()
        render profesores as JSON
    }

    def obtenerProfesorById = {
        def id = params.id as Long
        def profesor = Profesor.get(id)
        render profesor ? profesor as JSON : {status: 404}

    }
}

UrlMappings,groovy (En teoría la URL sería: http://localhost:8080/Curso/api/profesor)
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
        "/api/profesor"(
                controller: "api.ProfesorApiController",
                action: "mostrarProfesores",
                method: "GET"
        )

        "/api/profesor/$id"(
                controller: "api.ProfesorApiController",
                action: "obtenerProfesorById",
                method: "GET"
        )

        "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
            constraints {
                // apply constraints here

            }
        }

        "/"(view:"/index")
        "500"(view:'/error')
        "404"(view:'/notFound')
    }
}

Espero que todos estos datos sean suficiente para encontrar la causa del problema.
